# uploading an image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, image-processing

Recently I am getting interested in image manipulation. But I am stuck just at the beginning of the long journey.

I have a problem in uploading an image in asp.net mvc3(razor view) project.
Can any one suggest me a basic sample/tutorial how to do it so.

Comment: Tell us where exactly are you stuck/what are your problems and we`ll try to help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload an image just call this in your html.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
```

}

Be sure to have `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` or your file won't be uploaded.
Then from the controller just handle the Request.Files of accept directly a HttpPostedFileBase

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) 
    {
        //file handling logic
        file.SaveAs(/* your path here */);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");        
}
```

Remember also that classic file upload don't work with ajax calls. If that is the case you must use a plugins like [this one](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Comment: Thank you Iridio, Now I got this working(uploading an image). I have learned a nice library (aforge). I am trying to make further modifications on the image. like change it to 8 bpp scale.

Comment: Good luck than. Image manipulation and Computer vision are challenging :)